# ASP.NET Core 1.0/MVC 6 restart application programmatically

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

How can I restart the current application programmatically?

Basically in Startup.cs I need to load some services from assemblies which will require IIS Restart or the application to be restarted/Startup.cs rerun.

Answer (score 1):

Apps restarting themselves are always problematic.

Maybe you want to consider using something like [dnx-watch](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx-watch) which will watch your app and restart it when files change.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use IIS integration, you can use hack like this: edit (programmatically) your `web.config` file. IIS watches this file and will restart your site.

For example, you can append a space to the end of file.

Of course this will be 'cold' restart, whole dnx process will be restarted. Your site will be unavailable for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Could something like work to recycle the app pool?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "appcmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "recycle apppool /apppool.name:AppPool_NAME";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```